# client.private_channels and member.dm_channel are 'None'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot and in my background task, `client.private_channels` and `member.dm_channel` are showing up as `None`. Here is my code where I create a background task.

```
# run this code when client is ready
def my_run_task():
    client.loop.create_task(BackgroundManager())
    client.run(_token)
```

Here is where I defined `BackgroundManager()`:

```
async def BackgroundManager():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    await SendDM(ID)
```

and finally here is `SendDM()`:

```
async def SendDM(ID):
   member = client.guilds[0].get_member(int(ID))
   DM = member.dm_channel
   PC = client.private_channels
   await member.dm_channel.send('DM has been sent.')
```

Please note that `ID` is a hard coded string which I switched out for privacy sake. It is a valid ID and returns the correct member object.

`DM` shows up as `None` and `PC` is an empty list. How come I can't access the user's dm_channel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your bot either hasn't exchanged DMs with the user, or the DM channel was not retrieved when the bot started. Either way, you can `send` to the member directly, which will handle creating or retrieving the DM channel

```
await member.send('DM has been sent.')
```